# Laravel chek if respose status 401

Tags: laravel, api, http-headers, laravel-5.1

I am developing laravel 5.1 project and it gets some external API responses. It has authentication part. from external APIs I am getting 401 unauthorized exception. I want to call some methods if response status is 401.how can I do it. Following is the steps.

```
public function authenticateUser()
    {
        //get the user details from request


        //pass it into host api and retrieve the response

        //return if get 401


        //if not check existence of user


        //if exist create session

        //if not create user and create session

        //send authentication response to widget

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your actual code? Like how are you calling the host API? via curl?

Comment: @aceraven777- host API returns 401 status code if it is unauthorized.

Comment: @aceraven777: solved mate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got solution guys.

```
if($hostApiResponse->status() == 401){
//call the methods
}
```